# Circulation and line integrals.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The following is the problem I'm working on.

> If $\overrightarrow {F} = <x,y^2z,-xy^2>$, calculate the circulation of $\overrightarrow {F}$ over the surface $z=x^2+y^2$ bounded by $C$ using a line integral. $C$ is given by $$C_1 : \overrightarrow {r}=<t,t,0>  (0\le t \le 2\sqrt{2})$$ $$C_2 : \overrightarrow {r} = <4\cos(t),4\sin(t),0> ({\pi \over 4} \le t \le \pi)$$ $$C_3 : \overrightarrow {r} = <t-4,0,0> (0 \le t \le 4)$$

I tried to solve it using $\int_C \overrightarrow {F}・d\overrightarrow {r}$, but the integral seems to be too complex and I don't think I'm doing this right.

I don't think neither Green's theorem or the Fundamental theorem of line integrals are applicable either because I don't think the curve is closed or $\overrightarrow {F}$ not seeming to be conservative.

Can someone explain this problem ?
I don't need much of the calculation. It's more of a conceptual idea.

It would also be great if someone could explain what it physically represents.

Comment: Could it be that "circulation" is what others know as "flux"? Or perhaps this is something I haven't heard of (nothing rare)?

Comment: It doesn't seem so. Because if it is flux shouldn't there be a bounded surface with a closed line integral ?

Comment: Just a minor observation: the curve is indeed closed.  But it doesn't lie on the surface, so I don't immediately see why it's relevant.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Circulation is not flux.  The circulation around of the vector field $\vec{F}$ around some closed curve $C$ is the line integral of $\vec{F}$ along $C$.  Stokes' theorem gives this as the flux of the curl of $\vec{F}$ through some surface $S$ of which $C$ is the boundary.

Comment: Thanks @Rhys . I didn't know that.

Comment: @Rhys Does that mean I can just take the line integral over C ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curve $C$, as given, is a curve in the plane (it traces out the boundary of a 'wedge of pie'); the first thing to do is lift it to the surface using the equation $z = x^2 + y^2$.

The curve is given as three smooth pieces, so you will need to calculate three separate line integrals; these become ordinary integrals over $t$ via
$$
d\vec{r} = \left(\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dy}{dt},\frac{dz}{dt}\right)dt
$$

(Edit: I'm guessing by your question that you know the following, but I'll add it for completeness.  By Stokes' theorem, the line integral will be equal to the surface integral
$$
\int\!\!\!\!\int_S (\nabla\times\vec{F})\cdot\vec{n}~ dA
$$
where $S$ is the part of the surface bounded by the curve, $\vec{n}$ is a unit normal vector field, and $dA$ is the area element.)

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you !